# What does this C function declaration mean?

Tags: c, pointers, types, parameters

```
schedule_accept(int fd,
            int (*handler)(int, FdEventHandlerPtr, AcceptRequestPtr),
            void *data)
```

Apologies for seeming to avoid searching for an answer here but I don't know what the constructs are in order to search intelligently for them. Specifically I'm interested in what the second parameter means?

My best guess is it's an int (that refers to a memory location) that is composed(?) of a tuple of the three referred to types. Is this correct? If I was only interested in one of these (and I'm right in my description in the first place) how would I refer to it?

Comment: It looks like it might be a function pointer with the three types being the parameters.

Comment: A good tool to use in interpreting complex declarations is "cdecl".

Comment: Pointer to a function returning `int` and taking three parameters, the first being `int`, the second being of type `FdEventHandlerPtr`, and the third being `AcceptRequestPtr`.  For more information you need the actual definitions of types for the second and third parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int (*handler)(int, FdEventHandlerPtr, AcceptRequestPtr)
```

Defines a parameter named `handler` which is a pointer (hence the `*`) to a function, which returns an `int` (hence the "outer" `int`) and takes three arguments, namely one `int`, one `FdEventHandlerPtr` and one `AcceptRequestPtr`.